# weird byte things in powershell hexedit shows other data than script for removing bom bytes

Tags: powershell, utf-8, character-encoding

Original working file starts with letter F - which is visible also in online hexed.it as hexa 46 number.

My file (created and exported using powershell) has 3 extra bytes at the beginning - EF BB BF. I have a script to remote those bytes but it fails every time:

```
[System.IO.FileInfo] $file = Get-Item -Path $outname 
    $sequenceBOM = New-Object System.Byte[] 3 
    $reader = $file.OpenRead() 
    $bytesRead = $reader.Read($sequenceBOM, 0, 3) 
    $reader.Dispose() 
    #A UTF-8+BOM string will start with the three following bytes. Hex: 0xEF0xBB0xBF, Decimal: 239 187 191 
   if ($bytesRead -eq 3 -and $sequenceBOM[0] -eq 239 -and $sequenceBOM[1] -eq 187 -and $sequenceBOM[2] -eq 191)
    { 
        $utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False) 
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file, (Get-Content $file), $utf8NoBomEncoding) 
        Write-Host "Remove UTF-8 BOM successfully" 
    } 
    Else 
    { 
        Write-Warning "Not UTF-8 BOM file" 
    }
```

It says that I don't have utf8 bom file. 
$sequenceBOM contains: 70,73 and 69 and not 239,187 and 191. But hexaeditor shows that I have EF BB BF on the beginning of file. Which is very strange.. Rest of the file is OK but another software don't want to accept it with those 3 extra bytes. When I have removed them manually in hexa editor, file worked so it is what is necessary to have but why powershell is showing incorrect values? thank you!

Comment: I have tested the code locally with an utf-8 bom encoded file and everything works fine. On first run it removes the BOM and on second run it throws the warning, which is perfectly fine?

Comment: yes. that is expected behaviour.. but at my side, hexedit shows 3 bytes but powershell see different 3 bytes.. but thank you for testing the script anyway...

Answer (score 0):

code works. issue was in path and file name